# A Property of a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

its true that $\forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\forall \lambda\in(0,1)$
$$||x-\lambda y||<||x-y||$$

my idea: since $$||x||^2=<x,x>$$ then $$0\leq ||x-\lambda y||^2\leq  \ <x,x>-2\lambda <x,y>+\lambda ^2<y,y> 
$$ since $\lambda \in(0,1) $ then $$||x-\lambda y||^2 <||x||^2- 2\lambda <x,y>+||y||^2$$ but I have problem with $-2\lambda <x,y>$ as bounded ?

Comment: Your conjecture is not true. **Hint:** Consider $x = y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Take $\lambda \in(0,1)$ and $x=y\neq \mathbf{0}^n$. Then
$$
(1-\lambda)\lVert x\rVert = \lVert x-\lambda y\rVert > \lVert x-y\rVert = 0.
$$

Comment: but $x \neq y x,y\neq 0$  ?

Comment: Same. Take $y = \frac{1}{2}x \neq \mathbf{0}^n$.

Comment: @Infinito307 Let me know if the above does not answer your question.

Comment: yes, answer my question thank you for your time

Comment: @infinito307 Glad this helped! Consider accepting the answer ($\checkmark $ on the left), in that case.